# How to extract columns from multiple rows in Python using nested loops?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, extract, multiple-columns

I have a list with 3 sequences

```
seq_list = ['ACGT', 'ATTT', 'ACCC']
```

I want to extract the columns from the the list and store it in another list using nested loops in python

The final output should be

```
seq_list = ['AAA', 'CTC', 'GTC','TTC']
```

I have written the following code, but it does not yield the desired output.

```
column = []
for i in range(len(seq_list[0])):   #Length of the row
    for j in range(len(seq_list)):    #Length of the column
        column.append(seq_list[j][i])
         print column
```

Comment: Should not the last item be `TTC`?

Comment: Programs w/ syntax errors don't produce any output.

Comment: Why do you want nested loops, is this an assignment?

Comment: @alecxe : Thanks, yes I have corrected it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I prefer working with nested loops because I have to input sequences of unequal lengths, so I find it easier. So you have any other suggestions?

Comment: `itertools.zip_longest` with a default or maybe  `itertools.product` depending on what it is exactly you want to happen for uneven lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your method I made little modification, for each inner `for` loop i created a `string` and then after inner `for` loop ends i appended it to `column`:

```
seq_list = ['ACGT', 'ATTT', 'ACCC']
column = []
for i in range(len(seq_list[0])):   #Length of the row
    string = ""
    for j in range(len(seq_list)):    #Length of the column
        string += seq_list[j][i]
    column.append(string)
print column
```

**Output:**

```
['AAA', 'CTC', 'GTC', 'TTC']
```

Although you could use @alecxe code(using `zip` and `join`). I think it's cool and more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can ["zip" the sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> [''.join(item) for item in zip(*seq_list)]
['AAA', 'CTC', 'GTC', 'TTC']
```

Comment: @RafaelCardoso yeah, good point, change the wording a bit to reflect that this is an alternative way, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I do use this method, do I have to install a 'zip' in the Python library?

Comment: @asher nope, zip is built-in.

Comment: Where in my code do I have to place that line? I am quite unsure

Answer (score -2):

```
new_seq_list = reduce(
  lambda new_seq_list,item:
    new_seq_list + [''.join([item.pop(0) for item in new_seq_list[0]])]
  , range(max([len(item) for item in seq_list])) ,
  [[list(item) for item in seq_list]]
)[1:]
```

1. transform the original list into a list of list-of-characters rather than a list of strings
2. reduce that list once for each character in the longest string
3. each reduction, add to the new list a string consisting of the first item removed from each list-of-characters, joined together.
4. at the end, remove the list of now-empty lists from the beginning of the sequence.